# SQL Server y consulta con diferentes problemas (sqlserver)

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, ssrs

Hola a todos realmente llevo poco tiempo manejandome en esto del sql server, y recien tengo un problema, necesito hacer una consulta a una tabla para crear un informe con reporting services(SSRS).

Mi problema:

Necesito mostrar los beneficios de la empresa del periodo que el cliente seleccione como parametro y ademas tambien tengo que mostrar los beneficios del mes anterior a ese periodo y del año anterior es decir

BeneficioActual         BeneficioMesAnterior           BeneficioAñoAnterior

El problema es que cada uno de esos campos requiere un where distinto y no se como hacerlo he intentado varias maneras pero ninguna arroja los resultados esperados. Ademas de que reporting services no me deja capturar los valores de Conjunto de datos externos al tablix por lo cual no puedo hacer 3 consultas independientes.

Aqui detallo un poco mas el caso

En este caso deberá ser posible suscribir a distintos usuarios de manera que les llegue un informe con los resultados de los Clientes que tienen asignados como Vendedor. Se filtraría por período mensual y el informe deberá mostrar la información abajo indicada. Te paso otro mail para el tema de las facturas.

VENDEDOR
CLIENTE
PERIODO

```
FACT.MES ANALIZADO  BENEFICIO   RENT.%  FACT.MES ANTERIOR   BENEFICIO   RENT.%  FACT.MES ANALIZADO EJERCICIO ANT.   BENEFICIO   RENT.%  TOTAL AÑO ANT.  BENEFICIO   % AÑO ANT.
```

Filtros del reporte:
VENDEDOR: PARAMETRO(ClientesComerciales.COD_Vendedor)
CLIENTE: PARAMETRO(Clientes.Id_Cliente)
PERIODO: PARAMETRO (OperacionesResumen.FechaNegocio)

FACT. MES ANALIZADO: Es (OperacionesResumen.ID_Factura_Cliente   )
Beneficio:                           es (OperacionesResumen.Beneficio)
RENT%:                                es (un campo calculado)*
*(%: es el  resultado de la siguiente fórmula:  Resultado = (Beneficio * 100) / (Ingresos)
Donde Beneficio =  Ventas previstas + Ventas facturadas – Gastos  - Gastos previstos
Donde ingresos = Ventas facturadas + ventas previstas
)
Para los campos de mes anterior y año anterior se mostraran los mismos campos antes descritos con la condición de la fecha en función del periodo
Ademas de que se debe poder filtrar igualmente por vendedor y por cliente.

---

Consulta probada

```
select BeneficioBruto, @mesA as FechaNegocio, Clientes.[ID-Cliente], OperacionesResumen.[ID-ClienteFactura], ClientesComerciales.[COD-Vendedor] from OperacionesResumen 
inner join ClientesFactura on OperacionesResumen.[ID-ClienteFactura] = ClientesFactura.[ID-ClienteFactura]
inner join Clientes on ClientesFactura.[ID-Empresa] = Clientes.[ID-Empresa]
inner join ClientesComerciales on Clientes.[ID-Cliente] = ClientesComerciales.[ID-Cliente]

where (FechaNegocio = @date) and (Clientes.[ID-Cliente] = 69748)and(OperacionesResumen.[ID-ClienteFactura]=69748)and(ClientesComerciales.[COD-Vendedor] = 000030)
```

---

Otra

```
Select 
OperacionesResumen.[ID-ClienteFactura],
Clientes.[ID-Cliente] as Cliente,
ClientesComerciales.[COD-Vendedor] as Vendedor,
FORMAT(OperacionesResumen.FechaNegocio, 'dd/MM/yyyy') as FechaNegocio, 
OperacionesResumen.BeneficioBruto as Beneficio,
OperacionesResumen.VentasFacturadas as [Ventas Facturadas],
OperacionesResumen.VentasPrevistas as [Ventas Previstas],
OperacionesResumen.Gastos as Gastos,
OperacionesResumen.PrevisionNoContabilizada as [Previsión no Contabilizada],
OperacionesResumen.PrevisionPendienteCancelar as [Previsión Pendiente Cancelar]
from OperacionesResumen
inner join ClientesFactura on OperacionesResumen.[ID-ClienteFactura] = ClientesFactura.[ID-ClienteFactura]
inner join Clientes on ClientesFactura.[ID-Empresa] = Clientes.[ID-Empresa]
inner join ClientesComerciales on Clientes.[ID-Cliente] = ClientesComerciales.[ID-Cliente]
where YEAR(@mesA) = YEAR(OperacionesResumen.FechaNegocio)
--AND (Clientes.[ID-Cliente] = 36040 OR ClientesComerciales.[COD-Vendedor] = 052406)
Order BY FechaNegocio DESC
```

El resultado esperado es tal cual la tabla detallada arriba, la tabla tiene los campos:

Beneficio
Fecha de Negocio 
entre otro

Y debo rellenar los campos solicitados anteriormente como detalla la tabla

Agradezco cualquier ayuda llevo 4 días intentando sacarlo.
Saludos

Comment: Consulta aquí [qué funciones tiene Stack Overflow en Español para que puedas organizar el código o lo que coloques en tus preguntas y/o respuestas](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/1453/78). Es mejor que organices el código o lo que pongas en tu pregunta para que sea mas clara. Recomiendo que coloques en tu pregunta datos de prueba y ejemplos de los resultados esperados.

Comment: Deberias de agregar el codigo de lo que haz intentado, el resultado obtenido y el resultado esperado, y si eres tan amable, la estructura completa de las tablas. Saludos.

Comment: El codigo lo puedo añadir pero la estructura de las tablas no puedo son muy grandes a partir del codigo y de la explicacion que he detallado arriba se puede ver la relacion entre ellas.

Comment: TEnes que hacer una vista, que deje exactamente la tabla como queres. Esto que estas haciendo es un ejercicio comun para reportes de datawarehouse, y no se soluciona con un solo query, si no con un arrastre de querys.

Comment: hola buenos días gbianchi podrias poner algun ejemplo de como podria quedar la query

Comment: Tenes que hacer una consulta que devuelva cada columna que necesites y despues unirlos por algun dato (periodo?). Todo eso, lo tenes que meter en una vista.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que cada consulta que has generado para los periodos que necesitas, si arrojan los valores que estás buscando, por lo tanto, lo que yo haría sería una consulta con la clausula UNION y agregaría un campo a cada una de las consultas para identificar lo que corresponde a cada periodo, se me ocurre que el nombre del campo puede ser periodo y los datos que mostrará la consulta serán "mes actual", "mes año anterior", "año anterior", de esta forma luego podrás con excel filtrar por este dato en tu tabla dinámica, si es que lo has hecho así.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/380099)